# How to have an an in-app purchase to remove iAds

Tags: ios

I have an app I'm creating that will have ads. How do i go about having an in-app purchase to remove iAds. I have already selected that there will be an in-app purchase but thats it. i wasnt sure if there were some coding id have to do

Comment: Have you read the "In-App Purchasing Programming Guide for iOS"? There is a lot of coding you need to do.

Comment: no but i guess ill do that, i figured it would be just a few lines of code to add in Xcode

Comment: The answer is never "just a few lines of code to add in Xcode" :-)

Answer (score 1):

You have to do the following:

After the purchase completed successfully, store a `bool` value in the `NSUserDefaults` as follows:

```
-(void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue updatedTransactions:(NSArray *)transactions {

    for (SKPaymentTransaction *transaction in transactions) {
        switch (transaction.transactionState) {
            case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased:
                [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setBool:YES forKey:@"isPurchased"];
                [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]synchronize];
                [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];

                break;  
            case SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed:
                NSLog(@"Transaction Failed");

            default:break;
        }
    }
}
```

Then at the part of code where you add the Ad's to the view:

```
  if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]boolForKey:@"isPurchased"] != YES) {
        // Code to show the Ad's
    }
```

And thats it.

Comment: sorry for sounding noobish but where is the NSUserDefaults located?

Comment: [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setBool:YES forKey:@"isPurchased"];

Comment: if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]boolForKey:@"isPurchased"] != YES)
{

-(void)bannerViewDidLoadAd:(ADBannerView *)banner {
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1];
    [banner setAlpha:1];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}

- (void)bannerView:(ADBannerView *) banner didFailToReceiveAdWithError:error{
    
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1];
    [banner setAlpha:0];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
}

Comment: that is what i had but it gives me an error saying Expected identifier or '('.

Comment: Do you know how to write codes in Objective-c ??

Comment: yes only a little, im still a newbie so I'm still learning

Comment: how you initialize the iAd ?

Comment: I had put in the iAd framework then used the iAd banner view in my storyboard then added a code (i put it in my .m  because i was having problems with the iAds sometimes messing up of which i added at the very bottom of my .m file) that i was told to add from another question by another user in a different question then thats it I've got the iAd working in the simulator so i know it works

Comment: what is the name of your iAd object ?

Comment: ADBannerView is the name and in my storyboard view its named Banner View